# JavaScript: checking parity of alternate digits? [homework]

Tags: javascript, math

I have a homework question I've been having trouble with.

I have to write a function that checks if every alternate digit in a given number has the same parity. For example, both **1** 2 **3** 3 and 2 **1** 3 **3** are valid, but 1324 is not. I have no idea how to go about doing this, though. How do I keep track of previous digits, for one thing? Any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit:** My efforts so far:

Any number < 100 clearly isn't acceptable (right?) since 'every alternate digit' doesn't really make sense here. For 3-digit numbers, this should work:

```
    function validate(n) {
      var i, copy, l = [0, 0];
      if (isNaN(n) || (n < 100)) {
        return false;
      } else {
        copy = Math.round(n);
        for (i = copy.toString().length; i--; n = Math.floor(n / 10)) {
          l[0] = l[1];
          l[1] = l[2];
          l[2] = n % 10;
        }
        if ((l[0] % 2) == (l[2] % 2)) return true;
      }
    }
```

**Edit[2]:** Thanks for your help, everybody. I've managed to get an honest-to-goodness real (I *think*) working function based on [Salix alba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/865481/salix-alba)'s first suggestion to save the parities of the first and second digits. The loops run backward over the digits.

For now, this (along with making a couple of minor edits to save the parities of the last and second-last digits instead as Salix alba said, which would make the `parity =` lines simpler) is my solution:

```
function validate(n) {
  var copy, len, parity, broke = 0, i = 2;
  if (!isNaN(n) || (n >= 100)) {
    n = Math.round(n);
    len = n.toString().length;
    copy = n; // save
    parity = Math.floor(n / Math.pow(10, len - 1)) % 2;
    n = Math.floor(n / 10);
    while (i < len) {
      if (parity != ((n % 10) % 2)) {
        broke++;
    break;
      }
      i += 2;
      n = Math.floor(n / 100);
    }
    n = copy; // restore
    i = 1;
    parity = (Math.floor(n / Math.pow(10, len - 2)) % 10) % 2;
    while (i < len) {
      if (parity != ((n % 10) % 2)) {
        broke++;
    break;
      }
      i += 2;
      n = Math.floor(n / 100);
    }
    if (broke != 2) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

It's a horrible mess, of course. I would really, really appreciate any ideas for make this more efficient, easier to read, etc.

(Also going to try to write another function with [jing3142](https://stackoverflow.com/users/541667/jing3142)'s method of iterating with a flag, which *might* make the loops simpler.)

Comment: No help unless you post your efforts

Comment: If we write the answer do we get the qualification (or at least a mention like in the Oscars)

Comment: @mplungjan I just need a general idea of how to go about solving this, I'm not asking for actual code or anything.

Comment: Your nearly there. Its easier if you work with a string `var s = n.toString()` then you can work with the individual digits `s[0] % 2`.   Save the parity of the first digit then loop.

Comment: @Salixalba I was explicitly told to not use strings :( .. but I think I can save the parity of the first digit, then loop and check every alternate digit .. and then do the same again, saving the parity of the second digit and looping over the other set of alternate digits? There has to be a more efficient way. Still, I'll try to implement this until somebody has any other ideas.

Comment: In that case  it might be easier to work with the last least significant digit. You can get that using n % 10. You can loop through digits `x = 3477595;
while(x>0) { console.log(x % 10); x = Math.floor(x / 10); }`

Comment: You should be able to do it using a single loop. Save least sig digit d_0, loop to test d_2, d_4, d_6.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand :( that helps me check for 1,3,5 in 614325 but not 6,4,2 right? I need to check both sets of alternate numbers.

Comment: how about if I save the parities last and 2nd-last digit from the end, and loop through _all_ the other digits (not just alternate ones) using the parity of `i` to select whichever one of these two saved parities I need to compare with? that should work, but then what? I can't just `return false` immediately if I encounter a non-matching parity, since I need to check the other set too ..

Comment: I'm a bit confused on the test numbers: 1233 and 2133 are valid, but 1324 is not? Surely 1233 fails on positions 2 (digit 2) and 4 (digit 3) having different parity? And 2133 on positions 1 (2) and 3 (3) having different parity? The description would suggest 1234 is ok and 2143 is ok, but 2133 is not.

Answer (score 0):

You are working along the right lines but there are a number of issues. You code only works for three digits since your check `if ((l[0] % 2) == (l[2] % 2)) return true;` only operates once at the end of the loop.

So you need to set a flag, say `valid` and put `valid = valid && ((l[0] % 2) == (l[2] % 2))` inside the loop.

The loop will now fail because the first use of `l[2]` in `l[1] = l[2]` will be undefined since it has not been defined.

If you correct these then you will need to check whether there are an even or odd number of digits else it will fail for an odd number of digits.

Also you imply in your comment that you are not to use strings and in practice you do even if it is only to find the length.

There is another way.

The clues in your working out is that if n<100 then no check can be done, and that you need to reduce n be a factor of 10 each time through  `n = Math.floor(n / 10)` while you loop.

Rather than give you a solution as you ask for advice not a solution here is a hint.

given that n>100 to start with and if U is unit digit, T tens digit and H hundreds digit of n then while n>100 how do you calculate U and H, how do you then set the valid flag, in the loop?

EDIT Looks like you still need some help

```
Algorithm not code

function validate(n) {
    if(n<100) return not applicable
        valid=true
        while(n>100) {
            U=n % 10
            H=Floor(n /100) % 10
            valid = valid && ((U % 2) == (H % 2))
            n=Floor(n/10)
        }
        return valid
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry about the `l[2]` error, forgot to add the third element in the declaration. As for the strings, yes I was worried about that too. Any ideas for fixing it? Also, is using a `valid` flag more or less efficient/readable/better than Salix alba's idea of saving the parity of the first digit and checking against that? I don't mind rewriting the entire function, I just want the final solution to the best possible. :)

Comment: As for the problem you gave, I understand that after rounding n, `n % 10` gives the units digit, and `Math.floor(n / 10) % 10` gives the hundreds digit, and in general `Math.floor(n / Math.pow(10, x - 1)) % 10` gives the `x`th digit from the end? Is there another way of doing this? Sorry, I'm rather inexperienced and new to all this..